# display image limit one per result?

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a search script i am using. it finds users by name or location. i am trying to add a image to each user that is found in the search. but when i do it lists every users image even if not in the search and duplicates the searched name and image a dozen times like so:

image1.jp  user: michael
image1.jp  user: michael
image1.jp  user: michael
image1.jp  user: michael
image1.jp  user: michael
image1.jp  user: michael

image2.jp  user: eric
image2.jp  user: eric
image2.jp  user: eric
image2.jp  user: eric
image2.jp  user: eric
image2.jp  user: eric

and so on. can someone please let me know how i can limit it to just show one image for each user profile that comes up in the search without limiting the users that show up in the search to 1 obviously?

Heres my code:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="query" class="search" placeholder="Search Name/Location" style="width:120px;"/>
<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" class="searchbutton" name="submit" value="Start Search" />
</form>

<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="playtime";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_profiles
                        WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR orientation LIKE '%".$query."%'");
echo "<div class=\"results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
        $search_set = get_searched_escorts();
        while ($searched = mysql_fetch_array($search_set)) {
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\" class=\"search\">";
    echo "<img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$searched['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/> "; 
     echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div>";

}
}

mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to `GROUP BY user_id` or something similar?

Comment: what is get_searched_escorts() doing? while within a while could be the cause as your shown profiles query will not duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

try to place GROUP BY user_id

$query_for_result=mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM ptb_profiles
WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' 
OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR orientation LIKE '%".$query."%'
GROUP BY user_id");

Comment: @MatthewWilliams whats the result? is there a user_id field or try to group_by display_name?